# retrofitting an electric coil element with a radiant element

Tags: cooktops

We have a GE electric 4-coil cooktop from 1964 in our kitchen, in pink enamel finish with a matching range hood and separate oven. Is it possible to replace the cooktop elements with radiant types, or must the entire cooktop (lovely pink enamel and all) be replaced to get the easier-to-clean radiant elements?

Comment: give us the model and we will help you

Comment: this may be an option ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=solid+stove+elements&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible? yes. Is it practical? no.  First, you would need to find a glass top with element mounting brackets the same size and location as your existing cook top. Then you'd need to find the heating elements and wire them to your existing switches. Your existing switches would show "on" indicators but wouldn't be able to show "hot surface" indicators. This would be a real hack job and not be UL approved

You might be able to find a new cook top that would fit into the frame of your existing one after removing all the old parts so you could keep the pink color.

Your best bet is to just get a new cook top in a more modern style. Your other pink appliances won't last forever and I highly doubt you'll be able to replace them in pink so might as well start the conversion now.

Comment: [Replace them in pink](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Krylon-Decor-Selects-Gloss-Mambo-Pink-Spray-Paint-and-Primer-In-One-NET-WT-12-oz/5013056019). ;)

Comment: And if you cover it with a glass top (pretty much required unless somone made "coil replacements" with little glass rounds which I don't find) ...the pink stovetop becomes invisible under dark glass anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Likely not without creating an insurance nightmare, at least.

The physical form of the electrical interface is different.

So you'd have to swap parts for that. The control logic may also be different, requiring more parts swaps if so (I don't know that one way or the other, but I suspect it's true.)

They won't be UL-Listed for use in your stove - insurance nightmare if there's ever an issue.

Mind you, i don't see that they are easier to clean than a Calrod. If stuff gets on the calrod, you turn on the hood fan and run the element on high for a minute or two. If stuff gets in the drip pan, you yank it out in 5 seconds and wash it in the sink. If it's been abused past cleaning, you buy a new one, cheap, it drops right in...

Answer (score 0):

That would be a major surgery and not a DIY job.

It all depends how much you are in love with the "Pink" and your budget.

I would look for custom job done by professional that would make the modification safe and up to code.

You could go shopping for the parts sources so you have the info.